# Missing .sty files

Tags: miktex

I recently got into some sort of trouble. I reloaded Texmaker and then MikTEX, but when I try to compile Texmaker I get messages about missing .sty files for files that gave no trouble heretofore.. What can I do to get around this problem?
I'm running 64 bit Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you remember *how* you re-installed MikTeX? Did you by any chance select the minimalist version, which installs only very few packages initially -- and assumes that any missing packages can be downloaded, installed, and activated "on the fly"? If you don't want to go that route, consider installing the "full" MikTeX version, i.e., the one that installs all packages right away.